# Can't resolve 'material-ui/Button'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an existing react project to which i want to add material-ui library . So i have used the command `npm install --save material-ui`. But when i run it ,it shows error .

Here is the error details -

> Can't resolve 'material-ui/Button' in 'C:\Users{user}\demo2\src'

Here is the link for repository

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui

```
<Button variant="raised" color="primary">
  Hello World
</Button>
```

Comment: see https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7870

Answer (score 20):

For others who face the same issue in a future:

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

Comment: @BuddyBob, what do you mean by proper way? Do you mean on code? If yes, here's a sample code:
`import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';`

Answer (score 8):

The `Button` component that you are trying to use from `material-ui` is imported as Button from `v1` onwards which is still in beta stage. To use it you need to install it like

```
npm install --save material-ui@next
```

and then you can import Button from material-ui as

```
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
```

Check its usage as mentioned in [readme](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui#usage-v1-beta) of the git repository

In the current stable version, you have option of using [`FlatButton`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/flat-button), [`RaisedButton`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button), [`FloatingActionButton`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/floating-action-button) and [`IconButton`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-button)

Answer (score 2):

@Shubham Khatri's answer should be the accepted answer IMHO.

However, in order to use the Material UI library you installed, you should use it as in the example found in [the MUI documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button):

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const style = {
  margin: 12,
};

const RaisedButtonExampleSimple = () => (
  <div>
    <RaisedButton label="Default" style={style} />
    <RaisedButton label="Primary" primary={true} style={style} />
    <RaisedButton label="Secondary" secondary={true} style={style} />
    <RaisedButton label="Disabled" disabled={true} style={style} />
    <br />
    <br />
    <RaisedButton label="Full width" fullWidth={true} />
  </div>
);

export default RaisedButtonExampleSimple;
```

Keep in mind that v1.x versions of MUI are not backward compatible with v0.x versions.
MUI strongly recommends using v1.x in new projects even though it's in beta, as the amount of work needed to upgrade from v0.x to v1.x is so much more than v1.x to v1.y (been there, done that, and I agree)

Answer (score 1):

The following code will solve the issue.

Install the npm packages:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Import using :

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material/Button'**  ***Easly Fixed it.***

import it:

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
```

Installing npm packages involves:

**npm:**

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

**yarn:**

```
yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```