# React - Material UI | Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/Button'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI button on my react application page.

```
import Button from 'material-ui/Button'
<Button color="primary" variant="raised">
          Group
</Button>
```

I have installed below package -

```
npm install material-ui
npm install @material-ui/core
npm install --save material-ui@next
```

I referred all of this from existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789117/cant-resolve-material-ui-button).

But it proved to be of no use.

I am getting - `Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/Button'`

**EDIT 1 :**

After adding -

```
import Button from '@material-ui/Button'
```

I am getting -

```
 Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/Button'
```

Comment: `import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'`, as is discoverable from *any* of the source in the material-ui button docs page: https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/

Comment: Now after adding @ , I am getting - Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/Button'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/button/)

You have to import it like this:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

// OR

import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are importing from the incorrect path
it should be
`import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';`
not
`import Button from '@material-ui/Button';`